# Marquee Text Effect in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In the past, a kind of animation could be included in the text, in which if the text exceeded the limits, it would automatically scroll horizontally. This was done by including: `android:ellipsize="marquee"`, and the result was something similar to the one shown here:

[image]

The problem is that in Jetpack Compose I don't see a way to include that option inside the Composable Text, there is the `TextOverflow` that includes the **Clip, Ellipsis or Visible** options, but I don't know if there is a way to include or use the "Marquee" option in Jetpack Compose. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yet, it was achieved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from `1.4.0-alpha04` you can use the **`basicMarquee()`** modifier:

```
// Marquee only animates when the content doesn't fit in the max width.

Column(Modifier.width(30.dp)) {
    Text("hello world hello world hello",
        Modifier.basicMarquee())
}
```

[image]

If you want to add a fade effect at the edges you can use:

```
Text(
    "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs",
    Modifier
        .widthIn(max = edgeWidth * 4)
        // Rendering to an offscreen buffer is required to get the faded edges' alpha to be
        // applied only to the text, and not whatever is drawn below this composable (e.g. the
        // window).
        .graphicsLayer { compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen }
        .drawWithContent {
            drawContent()
            drawFadedEdge(leftEdge = true)
            drawFadedEdge(leftEdge = false)
        }
        .basicMarquee(
            // Animate forever.
            iterations = Int.MAX_VALUE,
            spacing = MarqueeSpacing(0.dp)
        )
        .padding(start = edgeWidth)
)
```

with:

```
val edgeWidth = 32.dp
fun ContentDrawScope.drawFadedEdge(leftEdge: Boolean) {
    val edgeWidthPx = edgeWidth.toPx()
    drawRect(
        topLeft = Offset(if (leftEdge) 0f else size.width - edgeWidthPx, 0f),
        size = Size(edgeWidthPx, size.height),
        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
            colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.Black),
            startX = if (leftEdge) 0f else size.width,
            endX = if (leftEdge) edgeWidthPx else size.width - edgeWidthPx
        ),
        blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 30):

**`Modifier.basicMarquee`** was introduced in `1.4.0-alpha04`. It's gonna animate position of your content if it doesn't fit the container width. Here's usage example:

```
Text(
    LoremIpsum().values.first().take(10),
    maxLines = 1,
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(50.dp)
        .basicMarquee()
)
```

[image]

It's not gonna add gradient edges, as XML attribute does. The tricky part is that this modifier doesn't has any state for you to know, if content fits the bounds or not, so you can't optionally draw the gradient. Maybe they'll add it later.

---

Below solution would work prior Compose 1.4 and also would only add gradient in case content doesn't fit the container.

You will need [`TargetBasedAnimation`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#targetbasedanimation), which will update the text offset, and `SubcomposeLayout`, which lies under most collections. Inside you can define the size of the text, and also place the second similar `Text`, which will appear from the right edge.

```
@Composable
fun MarqueeText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textModifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    gradientEdgeColor: Color = Color.White,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
) {
    val createText = @Composable { localModifier: Modifier ->
        Text(
            text,
            textAlign = textAlign,
            modifier = localModifier,
            color = color,
            fontSize = fontSize,
            fontStyle = fontStyle,
            fontWeight = fontWeight,
            fontFamily = fontFamily,
            letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
            textDecoration = textDecoration,
            lineHeight = lineHeight,
            overflow = overflow,
            softWrap = softWrap,
            maxLines = 1,
            onTextLayout = onTextLayout,
            style = style,
        )
    }
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val textLayoutInfoState = remember { mutableStateOf<TextLayoutInfo?>(null) }
    LaunchedEffect(textLayoutInfoState.value) {
        val textLayoutInfo = textLayoutInfoState.value ?: return@LaunchedEffect
        if (textLayoutInfo.textWidth <= textLayoutInfo.containerWidth) return@LaunchedEffect
        val duration = 7500 * textLayoutInfo.textWidth / textLayoutInfo.containerWidth
        val delay = 1000L

        do {
            val animation = TargetBasedAnimation(
                animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                    animation = tween(
                        durationMillis = duration,
                        delayMillis = 1000,
                        easing = LinearEasing,
                    ),
                    repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
                ),
                typeConverter = Int.VectorConverter,
                initialValue = 0,
                targetValue = -textLayoutInfo.textWidth
            )
            val startTime = withFrameNanos { it }
            do {
                val playTime = withFrameNanos { it } - startTime
                offset = (animation.getValueFromNanos(playTime))
            } while (!animation.isFinishedFromNanos(playTime))
            delay(delay)
        } while (true)
    }

    SubcomposeLayout(
        modifier = modifier.clipToBounds()
    ) { constraints ->
        val infiniteWidthConstraints = constraints.copy(maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE)
        var mainText = subcompose(MarqueeLayers.MainText) {
            createText(textModifier)
        }.first().measure(infiniteWidthConstraints)

        var gradient: Placeable? = null

        var secondPlaceableWithOffset: Pair<Placeable, Int>? = null
        if (mainText.width <= constraints.maxWidth) {
            mainText = subcompose(MarqueeLayers.SecondaryText) {
                createText(textModifier.fillMaxWidth())
            }.first().measure(constraints)
            textLayoutInfoState.value = null
        } else {
            val spacing = constraints.maxWidth * 2 / 3
            textLayoutInfoState.value = TextLayoutInfo(
                textWidth = mainText.width + spacing,
                containerWidth = constraints.maxWidth
            )
            val secondTextOffset = mainText.width + offset + spacing
            val secondTextSpace = constraints.maxWidth - secondTextOffset
            if (secondTextSpace > 0) {
                secondPlaceableWithOffset = subcompose(MarqueeLayers.SecondaryText) {
                    createText(textModifier)
                }.first().measure(infiniteWidthConstraints) to secondTextOffset
            }
            gradient = subcompose(MarqueeLayers.EdgesGradient) {
                Row {
                    GradientEdge(gradientEdgeColor, Color.Transparent)
                    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
                    GradientEdge(Color.Transparent, gradientEdgeColor)
                }
            }.first().measure(constraints.copy(maxHeight = mainText.height))
        }

        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = mainText.height
        ) {
            mainText.place(offset, 0)
            secondPlaceableWithOffset?.let {
                it.first.place(it.second, 0)
            }
            gradient?.place(0, 0)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun GradientEdge(
    startColor: Color, endColor: Color,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(10.dp)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(
                brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                    0f to startColor, 1f to endColor,
                )
            )
    )
}

private enum class MarqueeLayers { MainText, SecondaryText, EdgesGradient }
private data class TextLayoutInfo(val textWidth: Int, val containerWidth: Int)
```

Usage:

```
MarqueeText(LoremIpsum().values.first().take(90))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: there are some visual bugs: https://i.postimg.cc/BnPjxDCP/Screenshot-5.png I use it like this `MarqueeText(text = photo.description, color = Color.White, modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp).background(color = PhotoDescBackground, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)).padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp).align(Alignment.BottomStart))` As you can see there are white rectangle shadows at left and right

Comment: @user924 I've updated my answer for this use case, use it [like this](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/c2651646bca12c2dba697b73087e4dc2)

Comment: @PylypDukhov still the same error https://prnt.sc/HD-mrpQzxbcj On the screenshot you can see it for two bottom items. Also another issue that text for top items takes all width of item, but it's short text and not scrollable, so it should be wrapped by its width

Comment: @user924 You only apply shape for your background, but you also need to apply same shape to clip my inner gradient views. [This](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/f3d6f5db3b6167f5a38baf73abadcb43) should work

Comment: @PylypDukhov still nothing changed. Code screenshot https://prnt.sc/QiR4YJEExeaI How it looks https://prnt.sc/5EintsSD_Ni4 p.s. background color has alpha `val PhotoDescBackground = Color(0x80000000)`

Comment: @user924 looks good to me, how do you expect it to look?

Comment: it should not have white shadows inside text at left and right. how is it good?)

Comment: @user924 this is done by design =) If you don't need it, just remove `var gradient: Placeable? = null` and usages.

Comment: @PhilDukhov Can you give a deep dive of how your code works ?

Comment: When using on my compsable I have this error "Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported"

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, I wrote an [article](https://victorbrandalise.com/marquee-with-jetpack-compose/) detailing how it works

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution yet not perfect

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
var shouldAnimate by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}
LaunchedEffect(key1 = shouldAnimated){
    scrollState.animateScrollTo(
        scrollState.maxValue,
        animationSpec = tween(10000, 200, easing = CubicBezierEasing(0f,0f,0f,0f))
    )
    scrollState.scrollTo(0)
    shouldAnimated = !shouldAnimated
}
Text(
        text = value,
        color = Color.White,
        fontSize = 10.sp,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        maxLines = 1,
        modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(scrollState, false)
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139321650 for this. The code is available at : https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2334291/20/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/BasicMarquee.kt
It adds an extension function for Modifier.basicMarquee(parameters)
The code works perfectly fine for Text composable.

EDIT: You can refer here as well->

```
const val DefaultMarqueeIterations: Int = 3
const val DefaultMarqueeDelayMillis: Int = 1_200
val DefaultMarqueeSpacing: MarqueeSpacing = MarqueeSpacing.fractionOfContainer(1f / 3f)
val DefaultMarqueeVelocity: Dp = 30.dp
/**
* Applies an animated marquee effect to the modified content if it's too wide to fit in the
* available space. This modifier has no effect if the content fits in the max constraints. The
* content will be measured with unbounded width.
*
* When the animation is running, it will restart from the initial state any time:
*  - any of the parameters to this modifier change, or
*  - the content or container size change.
*
* The animation only affects the drawing of the content, not its position. The offset returned by
* the [LayoutCoordinates] of anything inside the marquee is undefined relative to anything outside
* the marquee, and may not match its drawn position on screen. This modifier also does not
* currently support content that accepts position-based input such as pointer events.
*
*
* @param iterations The number of times to repeat the animation. `Int.MAX_VALUE` will repeat
* forever, and 0 will disable animation.
* @param animationMode Whether the marquee should start animating [Immediately] or only
* [WhileFocused].
* @param delayMillis The duration to wait before starting each subsequent iteration, in millis.
* @param initialDelayMillis The duration to wait before starting the first iteration of the
* animation, in millis. By default, there will be no initial delay if [animationMode] is
* [Immediately], otherwise the initial delay will be [delayMillis].
* @param spacing A [MarqueeSpacing] that specifies how much space to leave at the end of the
* content before showing the beginning again.
* @param velocity The speed of the animation in dps / second.
*/

fun Modifier.basicMarquee(
   iterations: Int = DefaultMarqueeIterations,
   animationMode: MarqueeAnimationMode = Immediately,
   delayMillis: Int = DefaultMarqueeDelayMillis,
   initialDelayMillis: Int = if (animationMode == Immediately) delayMillis else 0,
   spacing: MarqueeSpacing = DefaultMarqueeSpacing,
   velocity: Dp = DefaultMarqueeVelocity
): Modifier = composed(
   inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
       name = "basicMarquee"
       properties["iterations"] = iterations
       properties["animationMode"] = animationMode
       properties["delayMillis"] = delayMillis
       properties["initialDelayMillis"] = initialDelayMillis
       properties["spacing"] = spacing
       properties["velocity"] = velocity
   }
) {
   val density = LocalDensity.current
   val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
   val modifier = remember(
       iterations,
       delayMillis,
       initialDelayMillis,
       velocity,
       spacing,
       animationMode,
       density,
       layoutDirection,
   ) {
       MarqueeModifier(
           iterations = iterations,
           delayMillis = delayMillis,
           initialDelayMillis = initialDelayMillis,
           velocity = velocity * if (layoutDirection == Ltr) 1f else -1f,
           spacing = spacing,
           animationMode = animationMode,
           density = density
       )
   }

   LaunchedEffect(modifier) {
       modifier.runAnimation()
   }

   return@composed modifier
}

private class MarqueeModifier(
   private val iterations: Int,
   private val delayMillis: Int,
   private val initialDelayMillis: Int,
   private val velocity: Dp,
   private val spacing: MarqueeSpacing,
   private val animationMode: MarqueeAnimationMode,
   private val density: Density,
) : Modifier.Element, LayoutModifier, DrawModifier, FocusEventModifier {

   private var contentWidth by mutableStateOf(0)
   private var containerWidth by mutableStateOf(0)
   private var hasFocus by mutableStateOf(false)
   private val offset = Animatable(0f)
   private val direction = sign(velocity.value)
   private val spacingPx by derivedStateOf {
       with(spacing) {
           density.calculateSpacing(contentWidth, containerWidth)
       }
   }
   private val firstCopyVisible by derivedStateOf {
       when (direction) {
           1f -> offset.value < contentWidth
           else -> offset.value < containerWidth
       }
   }
   private val secondCopyVisible by derivedStateOf {
       when (direction) {
           1f -> offset.value > (contentWidth + spacingPx) - containerWidth
           else -> offset.value > spacingPx
       }
   }
   private val secondCopyOffset: Float by derivedStateOf {
       when (direction) {
           1f -> contentWidth + spacingPx
           else -> -contentWidth - spacingPx
       }.toFloat()
   }

   private val contentWidthPlusSpacing: Float?
       get() {
           // Don't animate if content fits. (Because coroutines, the int will get boxed anyway.)
           if (contentWidth <= containerWidth) return null
           if (animationMode == WhileFocused && !hasFocus) return null
           return (contentWidth + spacingPx).toFloat()
       }

   override fun MeasureScope.measure(
       measurable: Measurable,
       constraints: Constraints
   ): MeasureResult {
       val childConstraints = constraints.copy(maxWidth = Constraints.Infinity)
       val placeable = measurable.measure(childConstraints)
       containerWidth = constraints.constrainWidth(placeable.width)
       contentWidth = placeable.width
       return layout(containerWidth, placeable.height) {
           // Placing the marquee content in a layer means we don't invalidate the parent draw
           // scope on every animation frame.
           placeable.placeWithLayer(x = (-offset.value * direction).roundToInt(), y = 0)
       }
   }

   override fun ContentDrawScope.draw() {
       val clipOffset = offset.value * direction
       clipRect(left = clipOffset, right = clipOffset + containerWidth) {
           if (firstCopyVisible) {
               this@draw.drawContent()
           }
           if (secondCopyVisible) {
               translate(left = secondCopyOffset) {
                   this@draw.drawContent()
               }
           }
       }
   }

   override fun onFocusEvent(focusState: FocusState) {
       hasFocus = focusState.hasFocus
   }

   suspend fun runAnimation() {
       if (iterations <= 0) {
           // No animation.
           return
       }

       snapshotFlow { contentWidthPlusSpacing }.collectLatest { contentWithSpacingWidth ->
           // Don't animate when the content fits.
           if (contentWithSpacingWidth == null) return@collectLatest

           val spec = createMarqueeAnimationSpec(
               iterations,
               contentWithSpacingWidth,
               initialDelayMillis,
               delayMillis,
               velocity,
               density
           )

           offset.snapTo(0f)
           try {
               offset.animateTo(contentWithSpacingWidth, spec)
           } finally {
               offset.snapTo(0f)
           }
       }
   }
}

private fun createMarqueeAnimationSpec(
   iterations: Int,
   targetValue: Float,
   initialDelayMillis: Int,
   delayMillis: Int,
   velocity: Dp,
   density: Density
): AnimationSpec<Float> {
   val pxPerSec = with(density) { velocity.toPx() }
   val singleSpec = velocityBasedTween(
       velocity = pxPerSec.absoluteValue,
       targetValue = targetValue,
       delayMillis = delayMillis
   )
   // Need to cancel out the non-initial delay.
   val startOffset = StartOffset(-delayMillis + initialDelayMillis)
   return if (iterations == Int.MAX_VALUE) {
       infiniteRepeatable(singleSpec, initialStartOffset = startOffset)
   } else {
       repeatable(iterations, singleSpec, initialStartOffset = startOffset)
   }
}

/**
* Calculates a float [TweenSpec] that moves at a constant [velocity] for an animation from 0 to
* [targetValue].
*
* @param velocity Speed of animation in px / sec.
*/
private fun velocityBasedTween(
   velocity: Float,
   targetValue: Float,
   delayMillis: Int
): TweenSpec<Float> {
   val pxPerMilli = velocity / 1000f
   return tween(
       durationMillis = ceil(targetValue / pxPerMilli).toInt(),
       easing = LinearEasing,
       delayMillis = delayMillis
   )
}

/** Specifies when the [basicMarquee] animation runs. */
@JvmInline
value class MarqueeAnimationMode private constructor(private val value: Int) {

   override fun toString(): String = when (this) {
       Immediately -> "Immediately"
       WhileFocused -> "WhileFocused"
       else -> error("invalid value: $value")
   }

   companion object {
       /** Starts animating immediately, irrespective of focus state. */
       @Suppress("OPT_IN_MARKER_ON_WRONG_TARGET")
       val Immediately = MarqueeAnimationMode(0)

       /**
        * Only animates while the marquee has focus. This includes when a focusable child in the
        * marquee's content is focused.
        */
       @Suppress("OPT_IN_MARKER_ON_WRONG_TARGET")
       val WhileFocused = MarqueeAnimationMode(1)
   }
}

/**
* A [MarqueeSpacing] with a fixed size.
*/
fun MarqueeSpacing(spacing: Dp): MarqueeSpacing = MarqueeSpacing { _, _ -> spacing.roundToPx() }

/**
* Defines a [calculateSpacing] method that determines the space after the end of [basicMarquee]
* content before drawing the content again.
*/
fun interface MarqueeSpacing {
   /**
    * Calculates the space after the end of [basicMarquee] content before drawing the content
    * again.
    *
    * This is a restartable method: any state used to calculate the result will cause the spacing
    * to be re-calculated when it changes.
    *
    * @param contentWidth The width of the content inside the marquee, in pixels. Will always be
    * larger than [containerWidth].
    * @param containerWidth The width of the marquee itself, in pixels. Will always be smaller than
    * [contentWidth].
    * @return The space in pixels between the end of the content and the beginning of the content
    * when wrapping.
    */
   fun Density.calculateSpacing(
       contentWidth: Int,
       containerWidth: Int
   ): Int

   companion object {
       /**
        * A [MarqueeSpacing] that is a fraction of the container's width.
        */
       fun fractionOfContainer(fraction: Float): MarqueeSpacing = MarqueeSpacing { _, width ->
           (fraction * width).roundToInt()
       }
   }
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
Text(text = "marquee text",modifier = Modifier.basicMarquee())
```

Comment: Samples available at : https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/foundation/samples/BasicMarqueeSamples.kt?q=BasicMarqueeSamples

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33603141)

Answer (score 0):

Since [Compose 1.4.2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.4.2) (or Compose March ‘23 BOM and above) you have basicMarquee modifier to animate your text in a marquee-like fashion. As a bonus, because this is a Modifier, you can apply it to any arbitrary composable to make it move in the same way :)

Check the refdocs for the [basicMarquee modifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).basicMarquee(kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.MarqueeAnimationMode,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.MarqueeSpacing,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) and some basicMarquee sample code [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/samples/foundation/samples/BasicMarqueeSamples.kt?q=basicmarquee).