# Text Marquee Bug in Compose Desktop

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

I'm using compose desktop and i want to use `basicMarquee()` on a long text with a normal `Text()` and RTL layout.

but it isn't showing correctly:

1. Text isn't start from beginning (این یک متن طولانی با قابلیت جابجایی است)
2. Text disappear for few seconds when it reach the start of text

My Text:

```
Text(
    maxLines = 1,
    text = "این یک متن طولانی با قابلیت جابجایی است",
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .basicMarquee()
)
```

My result:

[image]

i tried any `initialDelay`, `MarqueeSpacing()`, `textAlign`, `textDirection`, LayoutDirections and ... , but it didn't work.

Comment: This issues is not specific to Compose Desktop, it works the same on Android. It's a [known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/303194380). You can check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68980032/3585796) on how to implement it by yourself, and apply modifications to make it work for RTL.

Comment: Thanks, i already saw your response, but it produces this exception: `Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported`

Comment: It can happen inside intrinsic sized view modifier, e.g. `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`. you can solve it by adding constant size to `MarqueeText`. Or feel free to check other solutions in this thread, that don't use `SubcomposeLayout`